# How to lazy load views programmatically from storyboards

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard

In previous versions of Interface Builder, when I want to lazy load views programatically, I would do something like:

```
self.customView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil];
```

If I understand correctly, this was the proper way to do it. There does not seem to be a way to do this with storyboards, as there is no way to add a view into the storyboard itself(without being part of a view controller).

I have a view controller that manages multiple views. I do not want them all to be loaded on viewDidLoad, so I'd rather not include them in view controller's nib. Is there another way? if not, I could still create nibs and still use loadNibNamed. Can someone advise on whether this is an appropriate strategy, to mix nibs and storyboards? The fact that Apple has disallowed this kind of view loading in storyboards makes me slightly worried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone advise on whether this is an appropriate strategy, to mix nibs and storyboards?

XIBS and Storyboards are not mutually exclusive. There is no reason why you should not use both in the same application. I'm actually using multiple Storyboards and xibs in the same application. Works fine.

Comment: Is it certain then, that there is no way to load "part" of a storyboard?  They may work fine together but at times it's convenient to have similar assets near each other, and one might infer that storyboards are the beginning of the end for nib files (??)

Comment: Yes you can load any view controller from a storyboard if you want using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier :`. That doesn't mean xibs will go away, just like you can still build the entire UI in code, even though xibs might make it easier without code.