# Working with View Controllers in Storyboards

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I'm begin learn iOS and i have a question: when i launch the project, app will load all view controller or just the Initial View Controller in Main.storyboard?

In case, my app have a lots of view controller, e.g 50 VC, i want to check 50 VC  be loaded in one time or each VC be loaded when i call e.g like this :

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

After research and ask some friends, i see in Apple doc:

> The main storyboard is defined in the app’s Information property list
>   file. If a main storyboard is declared in this file, then when your
>   app launches, iOS performs the following steps:
>
> 1. It instantiates a window for you.
> 2. It loads the main storyboard and instantiates its initial view controller.
> 3. It assigns the new view controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes the window visible on the
>      screen.

Comment: just the initial view controller.. it loads other view controllers as you proceed to it!

Comment: Why don't you check it yourself? Welcome to stack overflow, please, read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please, learn the terminology: _lazy-loading_.

Comment: @holex: in this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161722/how-to-lazy-load-views-programmatically-from-storyboards, can load another view from Xib file, i know it, but i thinking about using Xib or using ContainerView in Main.storyboard, what's prefer and reason?

Comment: What have you already tried? maybe you can show us something you've done before: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/. Normally views will be loaded when needed. If you have a menu with a fix number of `UIViewControllers` you can do it on start.

Answer (score 0):

It just load only `Initial View Controller` set in Main.storyboard. You can set any view controller as initial view controller from storyboard-> `select any view controller -> go to utility portion of xCode-> go to attribute inspector-> now check is Initial View Controller.`

Comment: thanks iHulk, but i mean to check if i launch app, it will load all VC and show Initial View Controller, or just load Initial View Controller and show it.

Comment: @l3adl3oy Yes That's what I am telling you it will load only `Initial View Controller` on startup and then load all other VC on demand

Comment: i see, i update my question with answer, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**From Docs :**

> A UIStoryboard object encapsulates the view controller graph stored in
>   an Interface Builder storyboard resource file. This view controller
>   graph represents the view controllers for all or part of your
>   application’s user interface. Normally, view controllers in a
>   storyboard are instantiated and created automatically in response to
>   actions defined within the storyboard itself. However, you can use a
>   storyboard object to instantiate the initial view controller in a
>   storyboard file or instantiate other view controllers that you want to
>   present programmatically.

StoryBoard will load just initial viewController on load of the app. Other view controllers will load on performing segues or manually by following methods.

```
- instantiateInitialViewController
- instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
```

Read more at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html)